# How to Parse a CSV in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a CSV that contains fields that need to go to several Salesforce custom objects.  I've created the APEX class to handle the parsing.  However, when I call the class from a VisualForce page, I receive the message:

```
Collection size 3,511 exceeds maximum size of 1,000.
```

My APEX class is as follows (cobbled together from 2 blog posts on the topic):

```
public class parseCSV{  
public Blob contentFile { get; set; }    
public String nameFile { get; set; }    
public Integer rowCount { get; set; }    
public Integer colCount { get; set; }    
public List<List<String>> getResults() {        
 List<List<String>> parsedCSV = new List<List<String>>();        
 rowCount = 0;        
 colCount = 0;        
 if (contentFile != null){            
 String fileString = contentFile.toString();            
 parsedCSV = parseCSV(fileString, false);            
 rowCount = parsedCSV.size();            
 for (List<String> row : parsedCSV){                
 if (row.size() > colCount){                    
 colCount = row.size();                
}            
}        
}        
return parsedCSV;    
}  
public static List<List<String>> parseCSV(String contents,Boolean skipHeaders) {        
List<List<String>> allFields = new List<List<String>>();    
// replace instances where a double quote begins a field containing a comma    
// in this case you get a double quote followed by a doubled double quote    
// do this for beginning and end of a field    
contents = contents.replaceAll(',"""',',"DBLQT').replaceall('""",','DBLQT",');    
// now replace all remaining double quotes - we do this so that we can reconstruct    
// fields with commas inside assuming they begin and end with a double quote    
contents = contents.replaceAll('""','DBLQT');    
// we are not attempting to handle fields with a newline inside of them    
// so, split on newline to get the spreadsheet rows    
List<String> lines = new List<String>();    
try {        
lines = contents.split('\n');    
} 
catch (System.ListException e) {        
System.debug('Limits exceeded?' + e.getMessage());    
}    
Integer num = 0;    
for(String line : lines) {        
// check for blank CSV lines (only commas)        
if (line.replaceAll(',','').trim().length() == 0) break;
List<String> fields = line.split(',');          
List<String> cleanFields = new List<String>();        
String compositeField;        
Boolean makeCompositeField = false;        
for(String field : fields) {            
if (field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"')) 
{
            cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));            
} 
else if (field.startsWith('"')) {                
makeCompositeField = true;                
compositeField = field;            
}
else if (field.endsWith('"')) {
compositeField += ',' + field;                
cleanFields.add(compositeField.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));                
makeCompositeField = false;            
}
else if (makeCompositeField) {                
compositeField +=  ',' + field;            
}
else {
cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));            
}        
}                
allFields.add(cleanFields);    
}    
if (skipHeaders) allFields.remove(0);    
return allFields;       
}  
}
```

How do I ensure that the above class inserts the correct columns from the CSV into the proper custom object?

Since some objects contain lookups to others, how do I ensure that data is loaded into the lookup fields first, and then into the child tables?

Finally, How do I work around the error message above?  Is something besides use of a VisualForce page suggested?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Comment: How did you go about testing?

Comment: Too many separate questions here ("How do I parse a CSV?", "How do I fix this particular wall of code?", "Should I use something besides a VisualForce page?", "How do I fix this particular error?") for anyone to answer comprehensively in a way that will be useful to future readers. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of interest, is there a requirement for this to be from a visualforce page? You could just use Data Loader to load CSVs, or even build a solution using the bulk API yourself.

If you do need to do it from a page, I'd suggest that rather than splitting on a new line immediately, you use `substring` and the `indexOf` to pull just one line at a time from the input string, processing them as you go.

Comment: I was avoiding use of Data Loader since the CSV contains fields that need to be inserted into separate objects, rather than in one object.  For example, the CSV contains a CallFrom and a CallTo field which are to be loaded into the Calls object.  Those are lookups to another table, DID.  Thus, there must be entries in DID in order for CallFrom and CallTo to load successfully into the Call object.  Can DataLoader handle this use case?

Comment: Not in one go — is this to be a regular load or just occasional? If occasional I'd suggest doing the loads with dataloader and using the success file from the first load with a VLOOKUP to set the lookup IDs in the other tables. If it's to be a regular thing then maybe you'd be best finding an ETL tool to use?

Comment: Sounds like an ETL tool is the best bet as there will be routine uploads of this nature.  Aside from SSIS, do you suggest any others that do a good job in this space?

Comment: Pervasive and Flow can both work with Salesforce, but they carry a cost along with them (not sure of the details)

Comment: Data Loader is probably still your best bet, you just have to script a few steps and make use of external ID columns for joins. It's basic but it is solid, I use it for production processes regularly. Others to look at: Apatar (free but I'm not really a fan of it), DreamFactory Monarch (haven't used it but it looks good), Jitterbit. Pervasive is full-featured but also crazy expensive if you just need it for a couple tables.

Comment: Talend Open Studio for Data Integration is freely available and adequate for this sort of task. http://www.talend.com/products/open-studio-di.php

Answer (score 1):

I tried to process a 4MB CSV file and SalesForce returned to me a "Regext too complicated" error. I believe the issue is something similar to yours.

I fixed it using batch apex and an iterator. Further information is at [this link](http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/)

Answer (score 1):

This example from salesforce does not handle the case where you have single quote by itself.

For example,

```
",",XXX,YYY
```

This will return 4 fields when there are only 3

The issue is at:

```
if (field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"'))
```

When you have a field such as:

```
"
```

It both starts and ends with double quote but that is not the intent of the test

Change it to:

```
if (field.length() > 1 && field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"')) {
```

and it will work.

The full corrected example is:

```
    public class parseCSV{  
public Blob contentFile { get; set; }    
public String nameFile { get; set; }    
public Integer rowCount { get; set; }    
public Integer colCount { get; set; }    
public List<List<String>> getResults() {        
 List<List<String>> parsedCSV = new List<List<String>>();        
 rowCount = 0;        
 colCount = 0;        
 if (contentFile != null){            
 String fileString = contentFile.toString();            
 parsedCSV = parseCSV(fileString, false);            
 rowCount = parsedCSV.size();            
 for (List<String> row : parsedCSV){                
 if (row.size() > colCount){                    
 colCount = row.size();                
}            
}        
}        
return parsedCSV;    
}  
public static List<List<String>> parseCSV(String contents,Boolean skipHeaders) {        
List<List<String>> allFields = new List<List<String>>();    
// replace instances where a double quote begins a field containing a comma    
// in this case you get a double quote followed by a doubled double quote    
// do this for beginning and end of a field    
contents = contents.replaceAll(',"""',',"DBLQT').replaceall('""",','DBLQT",');    
// now replace all remaining double quotes - we do this so that we can reconstruct    
// fields with commas inside assuming they begin and end with a double quote    
contents = contents.replaceAll('""','DBLQT');    
// we are not attempting to handle fields with a newline inside of them    
// so, split on newline to get the spreadsheet rows    
List<String> lines = new List<String>();    
try {        
lines = contents.split('\n');    
} 
catch (System.ListException e) {        
System.debug('Limits exceeded?' + e.getMessage());    
}    
Integer num = 0;    
for(String line : lines) {        
// check for blank CSV lines (only commas)        
if (line.replaceAll(',','').trim().length() == 0) break;
List<String> fields = line.split(',');          
List<String> cleanFields = new List<String>();        
String compositeField;        
Boolean makeCompositeField = false;        
for(String field : fields) {            
if (field.length() > 1 && field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"')) {
{
            cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));            
} 
else if (field.startsWith('"')) {                
makeCompositeField = true;                
compositeField = field;            
}
else if (field.endsWith('"')) {
compositeField += ',' + field;                
cleanFields.add(compositeField.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));                
makeCompositeField = false;            
}
else if (makeCompositeField) {                
compositeField +=  ',' + field;            
}
else {
cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));            
}        
}                
allFields.add(cleanFields);    
}    
if (skipHeaders) allFields.remove(0);    
return allFields;       
}  
}
```

Comment: The current code doesn't account for fields that are in quotes and happen to end in a comma (example "My Data,").  To fix that, all you need to do is put the if (field.endsWith('"')) block in front of the if (field.startsWith('"')) block. This code also doesn't account for blank data at the end after a comma. For instance the string 'one,two,three,' will count as 3 columns, instead of 4. To fix that, change line.spit(',') to line.split(',', -1). This code will still be problematic on large strings causing contents.split() and contents.replaceAll() to throw a 'RegEx too complicated' error.

Comment: To make this work for large files, move contents.replaceAll() to line.replaceAll() and replace contents.split('\n') with a function that uses the Matcher class which can have it's region advanced and be reset after X number of matches.

Answer (score 1):

I've received that message too when I tried to store converted CSV data (over 1000 records) into a list to *display* on a Visualforce page.  If you are going to display imported records (which is a nice feature), you need to make sure the list you are displaying has less than 1000 elements.

To insert the records into a Salesforce object, do something like this:

I defined a class called "Util" with a static method called "parseCSV" (see below):

```
public blob importedCSV {get;set;}

list<list<string>> parsedCSV = Util.parseCSV(importedCSV.toString(),true);
list<Custom_Object__c> cObjsToInsert = new list<Custom_Object__c>();
for(list<string> line:parsedCSV){
    Custom_Object__c c = new Custom_Object__c();
    c.Name=line[0];
    c.String_Field__c=line[2];
    c.Currency_Field__c=decimal.valueof(line[3]);
    if(line.size()>4)
        c.Description__c=line[4];
    cObjsToInsert.add(c);
}
insert cObjsToInsert;
```

Usually, when I process a CSV and insert the data into Salesforce objects, I don't run into size-errors.  I've made Visualforce pages that import a CSV, processes the CSV in some fancy way, and then export the processed data back into a CSV,Excel, or text (fixed width) format.  I'll load the CSV on a Visualforce page and save the data as an attachment on a dummy record.  Then, I'll direct the user to another Visualforce page that grabs the attachment, processes the data, and outputs to the desired format.

I can't remember where I got this code, but it works like a charm.  I wrote **test code** for the **parseCSV** method too.

```
public static list<list<String>> parseCSV(String contents,Boolean skipHeaders) {
    list<list<String>> allFields = new List<List<String>>();

    // replace instances where a double quote begins a field containing a comma
    // in this case you get a double quote followed by a doubled double quote
    // do this for beginning and end of a field
    contents = contents.replaceAll(',"""',',"DBLQT').replaceall('""",','DBLQT",');
    // now replace all remaining double quotes - we do this so that we can reconstruct
    // fields with commas inside assuming they begin and end with a double quote
    contents = contents.replaceAll('""','DBLQT');
    // we are not attempting to handle fields with a newline inside of them
    // so, split on newline to get the spreadsheet rows
    list<String> lines=new list<string>();
    try {
        lines = contents.split('\n');
    } catch (System.ListException e) {
        System.debug('Limits exceeded?  '+e.getMessage());
    }
    integer num=0;
    for(string line :lines) {
        // check for blank CSV lines (only commas)
        if(line.replaceAll(',','').trim().length()==0) 
            break;
        list<String> fields=line.split(',');    
        list<String> cleanFields=new list<String>();
        string compositeField;
        boolean makeCompositeField=false;
        for(string field : fields) {
            if(field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"')) {
                cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"').removeStart('"').removeEnd('"'));
            } else if(field.startsWith('"')) {
                makeCompositeField = true;
                compositeField = field;
            } else if(field.endsWith('"')) {
                compositeField += ',' + field;
                cleanFields.add(compositeField.replaceAll('DBLQT','"').removeStart('"').removeEnd('"'));
                makeCompositeField = false;
            } else if(makeCompositeField) {
                compositeField +=  ',' + field;
            } else{
                cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"').removeStart('"').removeEnd('"'));
            }
        }  
        allFields.add(cleanFields);
    }
    if(skipHeaders) 
        allFields.remove(0);
    return allFields;       
}//END ParseCSV

@isTest
private static void testParseCSV(){
    string contents='Field1,Field2,Field3\n1,,Smith\n2,Fred,O\'Connor\n3,Destiny,"Awaits, DDS"\n\n';
    list<list<string>> parsedCSV=Util.parseCSV(contents,true);
    //line 1
    system.assertEquals('1',parsedCSV[0][0]);
    system.assertEquals('',parsedCSV[0][1]);
    system.assertEquals('Smith',parsedCSV[0][2]);
    //line 2
    system.assertEquals('2',parsedCSV[1][0]);
    system.assertEquals('Fred',parsedCSV[1][1]);
    system.assertEquals('O\'Connor',parsedCSV[1][2]);
    //line 3
    system.assertEquals('3',parsedCSV[2][0]);
    system.assertEquals('Destiny',parsedCSV[2][1]);
    system.assertEquals('Awaits, DDS',parsedCSV[2][2]);
}//END
```

I placed this code in a class called "Util".  If you have a blob, first convert it to a string, and call the method.   e.g.

```
blob b=inputBlob;
list<list<string>> parsedCSV = Util.parseCSV(b.toString(),true);
```